# CPU usage 100% in I/O operaitions

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I have a theoretical question about CPU usage. When the CPU usage goes to 100%, what does it mean ?  Does this mean, I have too large data ? Or does this mean I have too large files ? Or too large number of files ? or too much data on JVM ?

This is Java I/O operation done using Multi threaded application.

Comment: It depends on what the CPU is doing, but you can tell the difference between too much IO or too much CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your application makes more computations than what your `CPU` can manage such that your `CPU` is totally overloaded, proportionally it doesn't do much `IO` compared to computations because `IO` adds some latency that will consequently reduce the `CPU` usage, for example an infinite loop with no pause will consume `100 %` of **the affected** `CPU`.

```
while(true);
```

While an infinite loop with a pause will consume much less `CPU` as we will have less computations to be done per unit of time.

```
while(true) {
    Thread.sleep(50L);
}
```

Comment: You nailed it Nicolas.. Thanks.. I do have while(true) in my legacy code.. :-)

Comment: Warning a `while(true)` is not necessary the root cause of your issue, it depends on what it is done in the loop